# Add Directive Attribute to Directive Element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

I have a directive element:

```
return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template:   '<ul>' +
                        '<li {{myNewAttrDirective}}>Home</li>' +
                        '<li {{myNewAttrDirective}}>Products</li>' +
                        '<li {{myNewAttrDirective}}>Cart</li>' +
                        '<li {{myNewAttrDirective}}>Contact Us</li>' +
                    '</ul>',
        scope: {
              _showMore : '=showMore'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            if (scope._showMore === true) {
               scope.myNewAttrDirective = 'myAnimationDirective'
            }

        }
    };
```

HTML:

```
<my-directive show-more="true"></my-directive>
```

So essentially, if `show-more` is equal to true, then replace `{{myNewAttrDirective}}` with an attribute directive i have i.e `my-attr-directive`.

I have tried with the above if statement, but as expect, in the html, i am left with `<li {{myNewAttrDirective}}>Home</li>`

---

UPDATE:

Within my if statement, i can add an attribute via:

```
var item = element.find("li");
item.attr("myAnimationDirective", "");
```

Which is rendered in the HTML, but the click events do not respond. (They do work if i added them to my original directive however).

Answer (score 2):

Solved adding

```
$compile(element)(scope);
```

Comment: A more elegant solution would be to do the binding in the directive compile stage: The **compile** function allows the directive to manipulate the DOM before it is compiled and linked thereby allowing it to add/remove/change directives, as well as, add/remove/change other DOM elements. Let me know if you'd like me to showcase this example with some code.

Comment: @CosminAbabei - your solution sounds better, esp from a performance perspective. A showcase would be useful.