# Modify ng-show within directive template from link

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

I have a directive element:

```
return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template:   '<ul>' +
                        '<li ng-show="hideItem">Home</li>' +
                        '<li ng-show="hideItem">Products</li>' +
                        '<li ng-show="!hideItem">Cart</li>' +
                        '<li ng-show="hideItem">Contact Us</li>' +
                    '</ul>',  
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            var shouldHide = myService.getData();


            if (shouldHide === true) {
               scope.hideItem = true
            }

        }
    };
```

The link function performs a call to a service, the result is either true or false.

If true, i want hideItem to be set to true within my ng-show.

---

HTML structure:

```
<section ng-controller="NavigationController">
    <i class="home"></i>
    <i class="bell"></i>
    <i class="phone"></i>
    <my-directive></my-directive>
    <button>Submit</button>
</section>
```

Comment: you ask this befor http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35744655/add-directive-attribute-to-directive-element/35744719#35744719

Comment: No - i asked how to add an attribute, not modify a ng-show/hide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/tisipa/1/edit?html,js,output)

you can actually just `vm.hideItem = myService.getData();` since you want the boolean's value anyway

```
return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        transclude: true,
        template:   '<ul>' +
                        '<li ng-show="vm.hideItem">Home</li>' +
                        '<li ng-show="vm.hideItem">Products</li>' +
                        '<li ng-show="!vm.hideItem">Cart</li>' +
                        '<li ng-show="vm.hideItem">Contact Us</li>' +
                    '</ul>',  
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, vm) {

            vm.hideItem = myService.getData();

        },
        controller: function(){

        }
    };
```

I added `controllerAs: 'vm'` it's much more manageable by assigning a name to your controller and attach variables to it

Comment: Thanks, with the above i get TypeError: Cannot set property 'hideItem' of undefined

Comment: Did you add the `vm` as your 4th parameter in your link function? `link: function(scope, element, attrs, vm)`

Comment: Can you make a fiddle of your progress

Comment: This directive is a child of a controller if thats any use? NavigationController

Comment: By `child` what do you mean?

Comment: Ahhh ok, you must specify your controller in the directive, sorry, I've edited my answer it should work now. No, Being a child of another controller does not affect the directive in your case

Comment: Thanks - are you sure your answer has been updated??

Comment: Yes, I've included a demo as well

Answer (score 0):

You have to watch it :

```
scope.$watch(function(){
     return myService.getData();
}, function(newValue){
    scope.hideItem = newValue;
});
```

This is only if your service is not doing server-side requests, otherwise you'll spam the server.

Answer (score 0):

I think `getData` method can be called from anywhere in your application.

And you want to keep track of these changes in your directive. In this case, you can use the `callback`.

Live example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/6hxaoq7t/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($scope, myService) {
    $scope.resolve = function() {
      myService.getData().then(function() {
        console.log('resolved from button resolve');
      })
    }
    myService.getData().then(function() {
      console.log('resolved from controller loading');
    })
  })
  .directive('exampleDirective', function(myService) {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      scope: {
        value: "="
      },
      template: `<div>hidden={{hidden}} value={{value}} <span ng-show="hidden">ng-show="hidden"</span><span ng-show="!hidden">ng-show="!hidden"</span></div>`,
      link: function(scope) {
        scope.hidden = false;
        myService.addCallback(function(hideItem) {
          scope.hidden = hideItem;
          console.log('callback resolved with value ' + scope.value + ' and hide is ' + hideItem);
        });
      }
    }
  })
  .service('myService', function($q, $timeout) {
    var callbacks = [];
    return {
      getData: function() {
        var defered = $q.defer();
        //simulate $http call
        $timeout(function() {
          defered.resolve();
          //simulate answer from server 
          var res = Math.round(Math.random() * 10) >= 5;
          angular.forEach(callbacks, function(c) {
            //call callback with result
            $q.resolve(res, c);
          });
        }, 1000);

        return defered.promise;
      },
      addCallback: function(callback) {
        callbacks.push(callback);
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController" id="ExampleController">
    <button ng-click="resolve()">
      call getData
    </button>
    <example-directive value="12"></example-directive>
    <example-directive value="'ab'"></example-directive>
  </div>
</div>
```

When you anywhere using the method of your `getData` directive knows that.